# setting audio balance from command line

Tags: linux, command-line, audio

I'd like to set audio balance from command line (linux), I'v looked at 'aumix' (and googled around) but it seems it does not have an option... can you suggest any method?

Comment: `alsamixer` gives GUI in terminal, but it is not probably what you want

Answer (score 17, accepted):

With [amixer](http://linux.die.net/man/1/amixer), you can set the volumes of the left and right ALSA channels. For example,

```
amixer sset Master 80%,20%
```

will shift the balance toward the left.

Comment: what's the difference between `set` and `sset`, and `get` and `sget`? The help doesn't mention it.

Comment: A look into the source code shows there is no difference on modern versions of alsa-utils. `set` and `get` where introduced in commit c569788bf207a0aa6e4a475e36062a3546b689bb, for compatibility with a mixer API. So both work fine.

Comment: With pulseaudio: `amixer -D pulse set Master 80%,20%`.

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere for this answer and here what I got

1. Download Alsamixer.
2. Go to settings and select "alsa_amixer controls" or the second option under the mode
3. From all commands search for "Headphone Volume" and change the values to 63,0 or 0,63.

Comment: This is helpful, but it unfortunately requires a GUI

Answer (score 0):

If you are using MacOS you create an AppleScript:

```
# Start preferences with the right page
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "output" of pane id "com.apple.preference.sound"
    delay 0.5 -- If you get an error, it's possible this delay isn't long enough.
end tell
# Set volume balance to normal
tell application "System Events"
    tell slider 1 of group 1 of tab group 1 of window 1 of process "System Preferences"
        set value to 0.2
    end tell
end tell
# Quit system preferences
tell application "System Preferences"
     quit
end tell
```

Comment: Syntax error
System Settings got an error: AppleEvent handler failed.