# How can I play mono sound through only left speaker using cli or .pulse/default.pa?

Tags: linux, audio, debian, speakers, pulse-audio

I'm using Debian.  I know how to remap to mono...
load-module module-remap-sink sink_name=combined-mono master=0 channels=4 master_channel_map=front-right,front-left,front-right,front-left channel_map=front-left,front-left,front-right,front-right
... but how do I remap to get all sound (mono) through one speaker?

Comment: note:  this question was 99% answered by brunetton
https://superuser.com/a/1184812/969070
missing part is how to channel the new mono sound to one speaker only.  interestingly, the gui settings in GNOME won't let me adjust the balance of the remapped output.

Answer (score 1):

1. Downmix your audio channels from source sink to new mono sink with `module-remap-sink`, see https://superuser.com/a/1184812
2. Shift the balance to the left channel with `amixer set Speaker 100%,0%`, see https://superuser.com/a/317297

There are some explanation:

- Before (1) you have to configure source sink balance to center (0%
  or 100%/100% in Alsa) and volume to 100%.
- After (1) Master will have "Playback channels: Mono" and the balance
  cannot be adjusted, so you'll have to find with `amixer` all mixers
  capable of `pvolume` and having non-mono channels, i.e. `Playback channels: Front Left - Front Right`. In my case this was the `Speaker` mixer.
- Also, in my case there is right speaker degradation but on low level it's still works, so I've set `amixer set Speaker 100%,30%` until replaced the laptop speakers.